# Multiple git checkouts from a single repo with hardlinks?

Tags: git

Does anyone know of a way to get numerous "read-only" git repositories based off of hard-links?  In otherwords, I want subsequent working dirs off of a ~500MB repo to only be hardlinks thus making it just a few KB.

Short of that, any any feedback on my below insanity is appreciated.

---

Okay, now background:

I'm working on building a QA tool where I want to be able to hit:

```
1f381de1.somesite.com
9e010d42.somesite.com
...etc
```

As these projects include dynamic (e.g. `php`) files hosted by, for example, apache, I can't pipe all the output through something like `git show`, or I happily would (if anyone knows a possible way to do this, I'd love to hear it).

I don't want to do a `git clone` or `git-new-workdir` for each version I want to hit as I'll be copying all the live files in the repo.  As I don't want to constantly garbage-collect this project there may be a hundred versions or more "active" at one time and I don't want to copy what may be a ~500MB project 100 times.

So ideally some tool exists that allows me to get several read-only checkouts based on hardlinks.  If not, my current thinking is:

- Checkout the repository

  - make an "uncompressed objects" folder
  - unpack the `.pack` file if necessary
- I want a new version:

  - make directory
  - uncompress the commit log for the tree with `git catfile -p`
  - uncompress each object into the "uncompressed objects" folder (if it doesn't already exist)
  - walk up tree as necessary, repeating the above step
  - create hardlinks in my new folder to each uncompressed object

The ultimate result is that I have an uncompressed version of all the files I use in `.git/objects` with every file in a new checkout being a hardlink pointing at some file in that directory.

Comment: Any reason you can't script a soft link to be made to the work tree?

Comment: because I need checkouts of different trees at the same time

Comment: How about `git --work-tree=somewhere/else checkout some-other-branch -- .`?

Comment: Same issue -- The new working tree references real files -- which is fine in most dev environments -- but imagine the case when I have a 100mb video that doesn't ever change and want to checkout 100 versions of the project -- I'm going to have 10GB of space used for the 100 copies of this video instead of 100MB + 100 "0 byte" links (they take a bit of space, but it's trivial).  I'm nearly positive that `git` has no native way to do this (though it's possible something is user tools can somehow) which is why I'm looking for something 3rd party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into this, I ran across FUSE which I've heard about but never really used or bothered to wrap my head around what it really was.  It allows me to do what I thought was impossible -- proxy `git show` commands to OS-level requests for files.